# Kendo UI - Menu - Is there a way where i can get all the menu items to be the same width (equal)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui, responsive-design, kendo-menu

I have a menu with 7/8 options. I would like the width of these to be the same because when I try and resize the browser window and reduce the width the menu items go onto the next line (which is fine) however, its very messy. If the menu item width for all was the same then it would look neater. Can anyone help please?

[image]
e.g. I want it to be like the red rather than the blue (in image shown)

Comment: please make a fiddle or telerik dojo with your current condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the default kendo css:

```
#your-menu li.k-item {
     width: YOUR_WIDTH;
}
```

I haven't tested, but I'm sure you get the idea. Good luck.

Comment: But I'd like it to be responsive, so setting a fixed width won't be ideal. I've tried doing a % however its not what I want. Thanks for your help though

Comment: How are you going to make the kendo menu responsive? Are you going to modify the source css/markup? The fluid width is the best you'll do without doing extensive code modifications. Good luck.